# RecyclerView items with different heights with FlexboxLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-flexboxlayout

**How can I display my recycleview items in a row while keeping their original height?**

I want to use a recycleviewer with FlexboxLayoutManager.
Every item normally having their own height depending on their content.
However, every recycleview item on the same row always ending up with an equal height somehow.

How can I display my recycleview items in a row while respecting their original height?

**I need the items to be displayed like this:**

[image: Correct one]

**What I tried without success:**

[image: Fault one]
(The small items always stretches)

**My code where I set the layout manager:**

```
        adapter = new ProductAdapter(getContext(), productsList);

        layoutManager.setFlexWrap(FlexWrap.WRAP);
        layoutManager.setFlexDirection(FlexDirection.ROW);
       // layoutManager.setAlignContent(AlignContent.CENTER);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I have tried this `layoutManager.setAlignContent(AlignContent.CENTER);` 
However you can't set `alignContent` in a `FlexboxLayoutManager` for a recycleviewer.
The app crash because `alignContent` is for `FlexboxLayout` (not manager).

**EDITED:**
When using a `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` , this will solve the problem.
However you will lose the responsive behaviour of the FlexboxLayoutManager.

I created my own responsive behaviour for a StaggeredGridLayoutManager:

```
 DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dpWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density;
        int spanCount = (int) (dpWidth / 222);  // 222=total space for 1 item incl. margin

            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(spanCount, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Comment: Refer this [Link](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/) will help you to archive design what you want

Comment: there's no way to do this with FlexboxLayoutManager then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this as your `RecyclerView` layout manager:

```
recycler.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
```

Answer (score 0):

From your image I think what you need is [`StaggeredGridLayoutManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager)